# Powershell - Variable problems

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I wrote a script that will pull data from a .properties file (*basically a config file*).  Some of the data from the properties file has environment data (*i.e. %UserProfile%*), so I run it through a function (*Resolve–EnvVariable*) that will replace the environment variable with the actual value.  The replace works perfectly, but somehow the data seems to be altered.
When I try to use the values that have been run through the function, they no longer work (see results down below).

**This is the file contents of c:\work\test.properties**

```
types="*.txt"
in="%UserProfile%\Downloads"
```

**This is my PowerShell Script**

```bsh
Clear-Host
#Read the properties file and replace the parameters when specified
if (Test-Path C:\work\test.properties) {
    $propertiesFile = Get-Content C:\work\test.properties
    Write-Host "Parameters will be substituded from properties file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    foreach ($line in $propertiesFile) {
        Write-Host ("from Properties file $line")
        $propSwitch = $line.Split("=")[0]
        $propValue = Resolve–EnvVariable($line.Split("=")[1])
        switch ($propSwitch) {
            "types" { $types = $propValue }
            "in" { $in = $propValue }
        }
    }
}
write-host ("After running through function `n in=" + $in + "<-   types=" + $types + "<-")

# This function resolves environment variables
Function Resolve–EnvVariable {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True, Mandatory = $True,
            HelpMessage = "Enter string with env variable i.e. %APPDATA%")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$String
    )

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "Starting $($myinvocation.mycommand)"
    } #Begin

    Process {  
        #if string contains a % then process it
        if ($string -match "%\S+%") {
            Write-Verbose "Resolving environmental variables in $String"
            #split string into an array of values
            $values = $string.split("%") | Where-Object { $_ }
            foreach ($text in $values) {
                #find the corresponding value in ENV:
                Write-Verbose "Looking for $text"
                [string]$replace = (Get-Item env:$text -erroraction "SilentlyContinue").Value
                if ($replace) {
                    #if found append it to the new string
                    Write-Verbose "Found $replace"
                    $newstring += $replace
                }
                else {
                    #otherwise append the original text
                    $newstring += $text
                }

            } #foreach value

            Write-Verbose "Writing revised string to the pipeline"
            #write the string back to the pipeline
            Write-Output $NewString
        } #if
        else {
            #skip the string and write it back to the pipeline
            Write-Output $String
        }
    } #Process

    End {
        Write-Verbose "Ending $($myinvocation.mycommand)"
    } #End
} #end Resolve-EnvVariable


# Hardcoded values work
$test1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Paul\Downloads" -Recurse -Include "*.txt" 

# Values pulled and updated through function do not work
$test2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $in -Recurse -Include $types 

# If I manually assign the values, it works
$in = "C:\Users\Paul\Downloads" 
$types = "*.txt"
$test3 = Get-ChildItem -Path $in -Recurse -Include $types 

foreach ($test in $test1) { write-host "test1 $test" }
foreach ($test in $test2) { write-host "test2 $test" }
foreach ($test in $test3) { write-host "test3 $test" }
```

**Results**

```
Parameters will be substituded from properties file
from Properties file types="*.txt"
from Properties file in="%UserProfile%\Downloads"
After running through function 
 in="C:\Users\Paul\Downloads"<-   types="*.txt"<-
test1 C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\Test\testPaul.txt
test1 C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\Test2\File1.txt
test3 C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\Test\testPaul.txt
test3 C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\Test2\File1.txt
```

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve? Please describe the problem - not the attempted solution you think you need to solve the problem. Why don't you use Powershell version of environment variables like `$ENV:USERPROFILE`?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. Could you clarify your problem a little more?

Answer (score 3):

Two alternatives:

## 1. Use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`

If you switched to non-qualified string values and escaped your `\`, it would be as simple as piping the file to `ConvertFrom-StringData`, at which point you could expand the variable values with `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`:

Properties file:

```
types=*.txt
in=%UserProfile%\\Downloads
```

Script:

```bsh
# Convert file to hashtable
$properties = Get-Content file.properties -Raw |ConvertFrom-StringData

# Copy value to new hashtable, but expand env vars first
$expanded = @{}
foreach($entry in $properties.GetEnumerator()){
    $expanded[$entry.Key] = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($entry.Value)
}
```

Should give you the desired values:

```bsh
PS C:\> $expanded

Name                           Value
----                           -----
in                             C:\Users\username\Downloads
types                          *.txt
```

---

## 2. Use and dot-source a PowerShell script for your properties

This is lifted straight out of a page of the original Exchange Server modules - place all configuration variables in separate scripts, which are in turn dot-sourced when initializing a new session:

Properties file:

```bsh
$types = "*.txt"
$in = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE Downloads
```

Script:

```bsh
# dot source the variables
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot properties.ps1)

# do the actual work
Get-ChildItem $in -Include $types
```